# How signal module implements timer

Tags: python, multithreading, signals

Here is my code for timer

```
import signal, time


def timeoutHandler():
    raise Exception()

try:
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, timeoutHandler)
    signal.setitimer(signal.ITIMER_REAL, 5)

    count = 0
    while True:
        print count
        count += 1
        time.sleep(1)
except Exception as e:
    print e
```

It works great, what bothers me is how is this implemented by signal module(i do not posses great knowledge about signals)

I thought the implementation would be like

1. signal module would be monitoring the SIGALRM in a separate thread
2. As soon as it receives one it has opportunity to execute the handler
3. What I dont understand it how does it resume its control back to main thread(The exception is caught)

Sure thread is not what is in picture here and I think some OS concept I am missing over here.

Answer (score 0):

The "separate thread" is the OS itself. `signal.settimer` effectively asks the OS to send a `SIGALRM` to this process in 5 seconds.